# Regex for multiple of 10 ranges between 30 - 10000

Tags: regex

I need help creating a simple regex for a whole number range of 30-10000, with no special characters and multiple of 10 e.g 30, 40...9800.

Comment: Let me simplify the task a bit: you need to create a regex for a range from `3` to `1000` and just add a required `0` at the end. Have you come up with anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex to match multiples of 10 between 30 and 10000 would be:

```
(\b(?:[3-9]|[1-9]\d{1,2}|1000)0\b)
```

- `(?:[3-9])0` for 30~90
- `(?:[1-9]\d{1,2})0` for 100~9990
- `(?:1000)0` for 10000

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CrC84MRZyvM5O0KQ)